# Use unspecified index array php

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I've got an associative array with (it seems like) a dynamic integer.
The array:

```
array(4) {
    ["attendees"]=> array(1) {
        [4]=> array(1) {
            [0]=> array(9) {
                ["attendee_firstname"]  => string(6) "Privat"
                ["attendee_secondname"] => string(6) "Privat"
                ["attendee_city"]       => string(4) "Test"
                ["attendee_sex"]        => string(3) "Man"
                ["attendee_dob"]        => string(10) "1980-01-15"
                ["attendee_email"]      => string(12) "test@test.nl"
                ["attendee_phone"]      => string(10) "0606060606"
                ["attendee_speed"]      => string(12) "testt - seln"
                ["attendee_shirtsize"]  => string(2) "XS"
            }
        }
    } 
    ["registration"]=> array(9) { 
        ["user_name"]   => string(5) "admin"
        ["user_email"]  => string(0) ""
        ["dbem_address"]=> string(4) "test"
        ["dbem_city"]   => string(4) "test"
        ["dbem_state"]  => string(4) "test"
        ["dbem_zip"]    => string(6) "8888ZZ"
        ["dbem_country"]=> string(2) "BD"
        ["dbem_phone"]  => string(0) ""
        ["dbem_fax"]    => string(0) "" 
    }
    ["booking"]=> array(1) {
        ["booking_comment"]=> string(0) "" 
    }
    ["gateway"]=> string(18) "idealcheckoutideal"
}
```

For example, if I want to get the attendee_firstname I use the following:

```
$data["attendees"][4][0]["attendee_firstname"]
```

The problem is that the 4 could be anything. (But I can't change the way this works either, sadly)
Is there a way to set an unspecified index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reset keys with `array_values`:

```
array_values($data["attendees"])[0][0]["attendee_firstname"]
```

Comment: I don't actually understand his question, what is a `dynamic integer'?

Comment: @MehdiBounya It could be anything and could possibly change. It's a function that I cannot (not allowed to) change.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to have a 0-based index:

```
$data["attendees"] = array_values($data["attendees"]);
```

or this to iterate, no matter the keys:

```
foreach ($data["attendees"] as $idx => $value) {
    // do something with $value
}
```